# Floating points return wierd value

Tags: php, floating-point

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Practices to limit floating point accuracy problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528042/practices-to-limit-floating-point-accuracy-problems)

When I am adding a list of new totalSubs to a running total, PHP returns a weird value.
I have generated the below output (see line 40):

```
1 The total currently '0' (integer) + new TotalSub '-26969.55' type(double) = total '-26969.55'
2 The total currently '-26969.55' (double) + new TotalSub '249.6' type(double) = total '-26730.05'
...
39 The total currently '-164.89' (double) + new TotalSub '61.95' type(double) = total '-112.94'
40 The total currently '-102.94' (double) + new TotalSub '98.71' type(double) = total '-5.3300000000009'
41 The total currently '-5.3300000000009' (double) + new TotalSub  '50' type(double) = total '45.769999999999'
```

The PHP generating is:

```
echo ($count++) . " The total currently '$totalTrans' (".gettype($totalTrans).") + new TotalSub '$totalVar' type(".gettype($totalVar).") = total '" . ($totalTrans + $totalVar) ."'<br />";
```

How can I fix the 00000000009?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see.
Try multiplying the input data by 100 and then dividing the totals by 100 at the end.

Multiplting by 1 or 10 will most likely not correct it which might be due to the 2 decimals and by using 100 the values are now whole numbers (**ints**)

Remember floating-point data types (such as **DOUBLE**) do not represent exact numbers and are approximate.

You could use `bcmath()` for maths calculations in the future as using `number_format`() is no different than using `round`() without returning it as a string.
http://php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php

Comment: i gave the *100 to input, and total/100 at the end, and it worked. not exactly sure why still but works so cheers

Answer (score 1):

Use `printf` to solve that problem and make your code presentable at the same time:

```
printf("%d The total currently '%.2f' (%s) + new TotalSub '%.2f' (%s) = total (%.2f)<br />",
       $count++,
       $totalTrans,
       gettype($totalTrans),
       $totalVal,
       gettype($totalVar),
       $totalTrans + $totalVar);
```

Comment: looks nice, get errors with my $totalTrans tho, will keep trying